# Passing a string type to a function

Tags: string, function, powershell, function-parameter

I have the following code:

```
cls
$input = 'Hello World'
Write-Host '$input.GetType() = ' + $input.GetType()

function some-string-function($input)
{
    Write-Host 'In the function now'
    Write-Host '$input.GetType() = ' + $input.GetType()
    Write-Host '$input (value)   = ' + $input
    return $input.length
}

$result = some-string-function $input

"`$result = $result"
```

I am getting the following:

```
$input.GetType() =  + System.String
In the function now
$input.GetType() =  + System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple
$input (value)   =  + System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple
$result =
```

Can someone point out how do I actually pass a string to a function in PowerShell please?

Comment: read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13503181/520612. Why the `+` ? You don't need it in `write-host` as concatenation operator.

Comment: Make that an answer Christian. Well not just read this answer, but essentially give that answer here.

Comment: @EBGreen Done it! I did not want to be repetitive ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As clarification for my comment `$input` is a reserved automatic variable. 
If you change it in your `some-string-function` with another named variable you will have the expected behaviour.

Comment: Holy crap!  I have literally spent 6 hours over 2 days tearing my hear out over this...  I thought it was converting my input object!  Grrrr...   Fixed now!