# PowerShell param is an empty string when it's not

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search through files for a string given in parameters by NodeJS.

```
param(
    [switch]$raw,
    [string]$input
)

[string]$file = "*.log"
if($raw) { $file = ".\raws\*.log" }

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include $file | select-string $input
```

The problem is that I'm getting the error that `$input` is empty:
[image: PowerShell says $input is empty.]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) you shouldn't use that name in your code. Not sure if that's why it's breaking, but it's certainly misleading.

Comment: That would be it @TessellatingHeckler. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange difference between $\_ and \[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502949/strange-difference-between-and-parametervaluefrompipeline-true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @TessellatingHeckler for pointing out that `$input` is a reserved/automatic variable, and thus cannot be used like this.

Comment: Oh man, such a lifesaver.  I will note $profileName is also a reserved/automatic variable and I was having the same issue.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this thread, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2) is a list of automatic variables in Powershell